# How to make proper container component using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, components

In the project I work on there are list "manipulation controls", like:
[image]

The parts of this controls are the same at 90% of the pages. So I'm thinking about writing "manipulation controls" `Component`, so I wouldn't change sizes at every page, just in `Component`'s template if I need to (all these `col-xs-*`), or just copy/paste html for each input separately.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 form-inline">
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <!-- Search input -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <!-- Type select -->
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 form-inline right">
            <sort-by ng-model="sortBy" ng-change="setCurrentPage(1);" values="{{sortValues}}"></sort-by>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <items-per-page ng-model="itemsPerPage" ng-change="setCurrentPage(1);"></items-per-page>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is it a good idea to make such "container" component? Is there any tutorial on how to make it properly (some of the inputs might be hidden, i.e. list is small and there is no need for pagination, every placeholder, title are unique in general, so there might be many variables to pass)?

This is more or less architecture question, I'm not experienced in this, but to my mind the idea of writing such component is good. If I'm mistaken or the question isn't specific enough, please argument it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a good idea to turn reusable code into components.

Yes, passing configuration variables is how you would customize it for each use case.  Using `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, `ng-if`, `ng-switch`, `ng-class`, `ng-style`, etc  ... there are many ways to implement the options in your template.

When you have a large number of options, it is common practice to pass them as one object. (ie. `config="{foo: 'bar', baz: 'biz'}"` vs `foo="bar" baz="biz"`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a good idea: that's the purpose of  directives (or components, in the new 1.5x implementations): inject in your HTML some reusable components in an intelligent way.

Think if you ever need to bind a variable to your "containers": you'll be able to do it easily and with no pain at all, by using directives/components.

Alternatively, if you don't need any form of logic inside your "containers", you could use ng-include with templates to inject html in your pages, like this:

```
<div ng-include"myContainer.html"></div>
```

and somewhere in your "templates.html"..

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myContainer.html">
  <!-- content -->
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is Angular directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) are the angular 2 version of directives and are also available in angular 1.5 to ease the transition to angular 2

Comment: No, it's not: he clearly stated for components, a.k.a. a new form a directive

Comment: Ah, sorry, did not know that, I'm using angular 1.x only